# iOS Rich Push Notifications left side attach image

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification, swift5

[image]

I am working on iOS rich push notifications with attachments. I want to attach image show on left side of title and subtitle with circle.

Comment: You wanted to show image in place of placeholder left side the "NOTIFICATIONSAMPLE"?

Comment: yes I want a image on left side on notifications title. above image shows iOS rich notifications default behaviour with attach image.

Comment: on both local and push notifications

Comment: Apple does not support customisation of UI in Rich Push in place of the app-icon which is your requirement. The only possible way is to set app-icon and it will be visible there.

Answer (score 1):

Hey on the left side of title, there is an AppIcon , just set the icon for your app you will get the image there automatically and it is not possible to change programmatically its apple's default behaviour.

other thing for attachment using rich notification you can [refer](https://medium.com/@tsif/ios-10-rich-push-notifications-with-media-attachments-a54dc86586c2)